# How to get RSACryptoServiceProvider public and private key only in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, rsa, public-key-encryption

I am running below code to get public and private key only, but it seems it outputs the whole XML format. I only need to output the keys as shown in [Public and Private Key demo](http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/)

```
        static RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa;
        private RSAParameters _privateKey;
        private RSAParameters _publicKey;
        public RSACrypto()
        {
            rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
            _privateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
            _publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

        }
        public string GetPublicKeyString()
        {
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            xs.Serialize(sw, _publicKey);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
        public string GetPrivateKeyString()
        {
            var sw = new StringWriter();
            var xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RSAParameters));
            xs.Serialize(sw, _privateKey);
            return sw.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: See the second answer of this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047532/get-the-public-key-from-rsacryptoserviceprovider

Comment: @NthDeveloper: That answer has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: You can use the Bouncycastle C# library which is the easiest solution or you can try to hand code the generation of ASN.1 objects yourself which is doable but much harder.

Comment: In .NET Core 3.0 (preview 1) you can get the binary data with rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo() and rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(), I’ll post an answer tomorrow.

Comment: @JamesKPolk thank you, I used BouncyCastle C# library, please write it as an answer to close this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Bouncycastle C# library has some helper classes that can make this relatively easy. It is not well documented unfortunately. Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;

namespace ExportToStandardFormats
{
    class MainClass
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
            var rsaKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa);
            var writer = new StringWriter();
            var pemWriter = new PemWriter(writer);
            pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Public);
            pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Private);
            Console.WriteLine(writer);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

Starting in .NET Core 3.0, this is (largely) built-in.

## Writing SubjectPublicKeyInfo and RSAPrivateKey

#### .NET Core 3.0 built-in API

The output of the builtin API is the binary representation, to make them PEM you need to output the header, footer, and base64:

```
private static string MakePem(byte[] ber, string header)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("-----BEGIN ");
    builder.Append(header);
    builder.AppendLine("-----");

    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(ber);
    int offset = 0;
    const int LineLength = 64;

    while (offset < base64.Length)
    {
        int lineEnd = Math.Min(offset + LineLength, base64.Length);
        builder.AppendLine(base64.Substring(offset, lineEnd - offset));
        offset = lineEnd;
    }

    builder.Append("-----END ");
    builder.Append(header);
    builder.AppendLine("-----");
    return builder.ToString();
}
```

So to produce the strings:

```
string publicKey = MakePem(rsa.ExportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(), "PUBLIC KEY");
string privateKey = MakePem(rsa.ExportRSAPrivateKey(), "RSA PRIVATE KEY");
```

#### Semi-manually

If you can't use .NET Core 3.0, but you can use pre-release NuGet packages, you can make use of the [prototype ASN.1 writer package](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-corefxlab/package/nuget/System.Security.Cryptography.Asn1.Experimental) (which is the same code that's used internally in .NET Core 3.0; it's just that the API surface isn't finalized).

To make the public key:

```
private static string ToSubjectPublicKeyInfo(RSA rsa)
{
    RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(false);

    AsnWriter writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    writer.PushSequence();

    writer.PushSequence();
    writer.WriteObjectIdentifier("1.2.840.113549.1.1.1");
    writer.WriteNull();
    writer.PopSequence();

    AsnWriter innerWriter = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);

    innerWriter.PushSequence();
    WriteRSAParameter(innerWriter, rsaParameters.Modulus);
    WriteRSAParameter(innerWriter, rsaParameters.Exponent);
    innerWriter.PopSequence();

    writer.WriteBitString(innerWriter.Encode());

    writer.PopSequence();
    return MakePem(writer.Encode(), "PUBLIC KEY");
}
```

And to make the private key:

```
private static string ToRSAPrivateKey(RSA rsa)
{
    RSAParameters rsaParameters = rsa.ExportParameters(true);

    AsnWriter writer = new AsnWriter(AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    writer.PushSequence();

    writer.WriteInteger(0);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.Modulus);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.Exponent);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.D);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.P);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.Q);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.DP);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.DQ);
    WriteRSAParameter(writer, rsaParameters.InverseQ);

    writer.PopSequence();
    return MakePem(writer.Encode(), "RSA PRIVATE KEY");
}
```

## Reading them back

#### .NET Core 3.0 built-in API

Except that .NET Core 3.0 doesn't understand PEM encoding, so you have to do PEM->binary yourself:

```
private const string RsaPrivateKey = "RSA PRIVATE KEY";
private const string SubjectPublicKeyInfo = "PUBLIC KEY";

private static byte[] PemToBer(string pem, string header)
{
    // Technically these should include a newline at the end,
    // and either newline-or-beginning-of-data at the beginning.
    string begin = $"-----BEGIN {header}-----";
    string end = $"-----END {header}-----";

    int beginIdx = pem.IndexOf(begin);
    int base64Start = beginIdx + begin.Length;
    int endIdx = pem.IndexOf(end, base64Start);

    return Convert.FromBase64String(pem.Substring(base64Start, endIdx - base64Start));
}
```

Once that's done you can now load the keys:

```
using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(PemToBer(pemPrivateKey, RsaPrivateKey), out _);

    ...
}

using (RSA rsa = RSA.Create())
{
    rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(PemToBer(pemPublicKey, SubjectPublicKeyInfo), out _);

    ...
}
```

#### Semi-manually

If you can't use .NET Core 3.0, but you can use pre-release NuGet packages, you can make use of the [prototype ASN.1 reader package](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-corefxlab/package/nuget/System.Security.Cryptography.Asn1.Experimental) (which is the same code that's used internally in .NET Core 3.0; it's just that the API surface isn't finalized).

For the public key:

```
private static RSA FromSubjectPublicKeyInfo(string pem)
{
    AsnReader reader = new AsnReader(PemToBer(pem, SubjectPublicKeyInfo), AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    AsnReader spki = reader.ReadSequence();
    reader.ThrowIfNotEmpty();

    AsnReader algorithmId = spki.ReadSequence();

    if (algorithmId.ReadObjectIdentifierAsString() != "1.2.840.113549.1.1.1")
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    algorithmId.ReadNull();
    algorithmId.ThrowIfNotEmpty();

    AsnReader rsaPublicKey = spki.ReadSequence();

    RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPublicKey),
        Exponent = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPublicKey),
    };

    rsaPublicKey.ThrowIfNotEmpty();

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
    return rsa;
}

private static byte[] ReadNormalizedInteger(AsnReader reader)
{
    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = reader.ReadIntegerBytes();
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = memory.Span;

    if (span[0] == 0)
    {
        span = span.Slice(1);
    }

    return span.ToArray();
}
```

And because the private key values have to have the correct size arrays, the private key one is just a little trickier:

```
private static RSA FromRSAPrivateKey(string pem)
{
    AsnReader reader = new AsnReader(PemToBer(pem, RsaPrivateKey), AsnEncodingRules.DER);
    AsnReader rsaPrivateKey = reader.ReadSequence();
    reader.ThrowIfNotEmpty();

    if (!rsaPrivateKey.TryReadInt32(out int version) || version != 0)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }

    byte[] modulus = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey);
    int halfModulusLen = (modulus.Length + 1) / 2;

    RSAParameters rsaParameters = new RSAParameters
    {
        Modulus = modulus,
        Exponent = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey),
        D = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, modulus.Length),
        P = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, halfModulusLen),
        Q = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, halfModulusLen),
        DP = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, halfModulusLen),
        DQ = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, halfModulusLen),
        InverseQ = ReadNormalizedInteger(rsaPrivateKey, halfModulusLen),
    };

    rsaPrivateKey.ThrowIfNotEmpty();

    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);
    return rsa;
}

private static byte[] ReadNormalizedInteger(AsnReader reader, int length)
{
    ReadOnlyMemory<byte> memory = reader.ReadIntegerBytes();
    ReadOnlySpan<byte> span = memory.Span;

    if (span[0] == 0)
    {
        span = span.Slice(1);
    }

    byte[] buf = new byte[length];
    int skipSize = length - span.Length;
    span.CopyTo(buf.AsSpan(skipSize));
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Will the Asn Reader/Writer be included in an official nuget targetting netstandard ? Not in the experimental myget feed that is.

Comment: @cleftheris That's not something really known at this time. You could express particular support matrix desires at https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/21833.

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to the above answer, to get public and private key separately in string format, you can use the following code snippet.

```
public static void GenerateKeyPair()
{
  try
  {
    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    var rsaKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa);
    
    //Getting publickey
    TextWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();
    PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
    pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Public);
    publicKey = textWriter.ToString();

    //Getting privatekey
    textWriter = new StringWriter();
    pemWriter = new PemWriter(textWriter);
    pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Private);
    privateKey = textWriter.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("public key, {0}", publicKey);
    Console.WriteLine("private key, {0}", privateKey);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine($"GenerateKeyPair Failed with {e}");
    Console.WriteLine(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to extract public and private key as char array, and not as string. I found one solution which is a modification of answers provided by James and Vikram above. It could be helpful for someone looking for it.

```
public static void GenerateKeyPair()
{
  char[] private_key= null;
  char[] public_key=null;
  RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
  var rsaKeyPair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsa);

  //PrivateKey
  MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  TextWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
  PemWriter pemWriter = new PemWriter(streamWriter);
  pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Private);
  streamWriter.Flush();
  byte[] bytearray = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
  private_key = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytearray);

  //PublicKey
  memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
  streamWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream);
  pemWriter = new PemWriter(streamWriter);
  pemWriter.WriteObject(rsaKeyPair.Public);
  streamWriter.Flush();
  bytearray = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
  public_key = Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(bytearray);
}
```