# How to create certificate object from public key in PEM format?

Tags: c#, itext, digital-signature, x509certificate, itext7

I want to use iText to embed signed hash and public in PDF.

As per arguments to sign method in iText 7 I need to pass certificate chain,

How can I create this certificate object directly from public key string?

**Update 1**
Below is small c# code. You can see I am trying to get x509 certificate from public key. This certificate will be used to verify the signed data from corresponding private key. Also it will be used to embed this public certificate and signed hash into PDF for digital signature.

In below code I am getting error as below

**Error:**

*'DigiSignDemo.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: DigiSignDemo.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\xposs\source\repos\DigiSignDemo\bin\Debug\itext.forms.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
Exception thrown: 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' in mscorlib.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Cannot find the requested object.*

```
 public static readonly string publickey = @"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuGhYfAvWxqIwsZsO1zUN
NyFT/3US7HGLXiW48NvYn2qNyn/9hm/BFWG901YoJAjlPTcNtMo1t8lUr2dRkc3l
8YyP8SetWKbznerQuXYBZZy31kp8u3Wj+zQSroZsFn69FoMAMWXqhkw9woFumINe
gw4sMtQ1S8CucX0uXJ4a2ElzoaUKp1M+MOCATDnmsXSyf/2/ERO71SpD+alDV2rE
m5DqvEnE0t27fm7PpNeCX0XEHRvx620LooGv1Co+0w5Au37sfSjOZp1B9V0n8KFR
6gLFY7mAZ1krZJscYgkNAPIz2QE6voBR8OVSHMnNcPH+0KLfGuNVHhaTyI4naPH+
0QIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
";

  public static System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate getPublicCertificate()
        {

//Here below I am getting error
                   X509Certificate2 clientCertificate =
    new X509Certificate2(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(publickey));

            return clientCertificate;
        }
```

Comment: If all you have is a public key (e.g. "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n..."), you can't.  But if you share more details about what you have, what you tried, and what didn't work, it's more likely the question can be answered.

Comment: I have updated sample code above. Can you please have look?
I am going to use this to verify signed data which was signed with pkcs1 private key

Answer (score 2):

You can't create a certificate from a public key.  It's analogous to asking how to create a car from a steering wheel... you're missing a lot of other stuff before it'd be a car.

Given that you have an RSA public key in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo format, you can import it as an RSA key, starting with .NET Core 3.0, via

```
RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
rsa.ImportSubjectPublicKeyInfo(
    Convert.FromBase64String(@"
        MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAuGhYfAvWxqIwsZsO1zUN
        NyFT/3US7HGLXiW48NvYn2qNyn/9hm/BFWG901YoJAjlPTcNtMo1t8lUr2dRkc3l
        8YyP8SetWKbznerQuXYBZZy31kp8u3Wj+zQSroZsFn69FoMAMWXqhkw9woFumINe
        gw4sMtQ1S8CucX0uXJ4a2ElzoaUKp1M+MOCATDnmsXSyf/2/ERO71SpD+alDV2rE
        m5DqvEnE0t27fm7PpNeCX0XEHRvx620LooGv1Co+0w5Au37sfSjOZp1B9V0n8KFR
        6gLFY7mAZ1krZJscYgkNAPIz2QE6voBR8OVSHMnNcPH+0KLfGuNVHhaTyI4naPH+
        0QIDAQAB"),
    out _);

// the key is loaded now.
```

If you're not on .NET Core, this is a lot harder.  See [How to load the RSA public key from file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11506891/how-to-load-the-rsa-public-key-from-file-in-c-sharp) or [How to get RSACryptoServiceProvider public and private key only in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997902/how-to-get-rsacryptoserviceprovider-public-and-private-key-only-in-c-sharp/54011211#54011211) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

@bartonjs in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866606/1729265) already has mentioned that a X509 certificate is much more than a public key. Here comes an overwiew to show how much more.

For this let's look at a specification of X509 certificates, [RFC 5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280). The certificate structure is specified in ASN.1 which is quite easy to follow even if one does not know it yet.

Here you'll see that first of all a X509 certificate is something signed:

```
Certificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    tbsCertificate       TBSCertificate,
    signatureAlgorithm   AlgorithmIdentifier,
    signatureValue       BIT STRING  }
```

The private key used for this signature may again be associated with the public key of another certificate (*issuer certificate*) which again may be signed using a private key associated with the public key of yet another certificate. This gives rise to a chain of certificates which usually ends in a certificate which is signed using the private key of this certificate itself, a *self-signed certificate*.

To verify whether one trusts the information in a certificate, one usually follows its issuer chain and checks whether one eventually gets to some certificate which is from a small collection of certificates one trusts explicitly.

The `TBSCertificate` in it contains the information to-be-signed. It is specified as

```
TBSCertificate  ::=  SEQUENCE  {
    version         [0]  EXPLICIT Version DEFAULT v1,
    serialNumber         CertificateSerialNumber,
    signature            AlgorithmIdentifier,
    issuer               Name,
    validity             Validity,
    subject              Name,
    subjectPublicKeyInfo SubjectPublicKeyInfo,
    issuerUniqueID  [1]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
    subjectUniqueID [2]  IMPLICIT UniqueIdentifier OPTIONAL,
    extensions      [3]  EXPLICIT Extensions OPTIONAL
    }
```

Here you in particular a subject Name, an issue Name and a serialNumber. The subject name describes the holder of this certificate, the issue name is the subject name of the issuer certificate, and the serial number is a unique number determined by the issuer when signing the certificate.

The validity interval indicates the intended time span of validity of the certificate.

Then there eventually is the `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` which contains the public key of the certificate.

Finally the extensions are an optional collection containing extra information like the allowed usages of the certificate (and its private key) and URLs where revocation information for the certificate can be retrieved.

---

As you can see you cannot simply *the certificate* based on the *public key* alone. You can create ***a** certificate* based thereon alone but don't expect anyone to trust it.